# Create point and lines in QGIS 2.18?

Tags: qgis, vector, point, line

I'm trying to do something very simple, to create **points** and **lines** in a new vector layer. With the 'Add Feature' button I can create polygons, but I can't find any tool to create points and/or lines. Is there a way to do so?

I've tried all of this tools and can't seem to find it:

[image: qgis digitizing toolbar]

Comment: if you're using shapefiles, you'll have to create new point and line shapefiles to store your data... you can't add points and lines to a polygon shapefile... from the Layer menu > create layer > new shapefile layer, and ensure you're choosing the point and line options...

Answer (score 9):

Go to layer menu:

[image]

Create new layer:

[image]

### Select point (or line) type:

[image]

You'll be able to add points, same scenario for lines:

[image]